# How to set height dynamically to listview with webview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a listview of webviews in a scrollview. Initially listview showing 5 rows with proper height, till the webview content not loaded. Once the content loaded in webview (through a network call), Now i can see only 3 rows with increased height, not sure weather the listview height is increased or scrollview height is increased or not.
here is the xml code,

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativeLayout"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/bg_img_welcome" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                android:paddingRight="25dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"

                android:src="@drawable/rashays_rewards_logo" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/welcome"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                android:paddingRight="25dp"

                android:src="@drawable/welcome" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/welcome"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp">

                <insessor.typeface.TextViewGothic
                    android:id="@+id/customer_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="CUSTOMER NAME"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.RoundedImageView
                    android:id="@+id/customer_profile_picture"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/customer_name"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/user_placeholder"
                    app:siBorderColor="@color/white"
                    app:siBorderWidth="3dp"
                    app:siRadius="6dp"

                    app:siSquare="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:background="@color/bg_drack_gray"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/bg_drack_gray"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <insessor.typeface.TextViewchunk
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:text="$"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />

                <insessor.typeface.TextViewchunk
                    android:id="@+id/reward_points"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="222"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="50dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <insessor.typeface.TextViewGothic
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Rashay’s Reward Points"
                android:textColor="@color/rashays_orenge"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/redeem_dollar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/redeem_dollar" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/contactus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/contactus" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/menu" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/booking"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/booking" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <insessor.typeface.TextViewGothicBold
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:letterSpacing=".2"
                android:text="NEWSFEED"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1px"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@color/separator" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/newsfeed_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </ListView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <include
            layout="@layout/footer_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout3"
            />


    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I think the webview content is loading late. 
Updated the code. added images,

sreenshot before webview content load,

[image]

sreenshot after webview content load,

[image]

Comment: `I have a listview of webviews in a scrollview.` So you have a scrollable in a scrollable in a scrollable... What a horrible design. Not even to mention the useless layout nesting.

Comment: I agree with Frank you have 3 scrollables. I would suggest to have just a list view with content that opens a new fragment or activity and inside of the activity you have the web view. To keep in mind having multiple instances of web view in on activity would easily kill you app.

Comment: there are couple of other layouts as well. thanks for notifying. let me update the question.

Comment: hi Frank/ Subsipder, I updated the code now.

Comment: the page heigh is more then screen height, so I used scroll view and added listview inside that

Comment: provide some screenshots, they would explain problem better

Comment: @KaranMer, added screenshots as well.

Comment: @IndraKP theres no need for scorll view when you are using listview, just remove the scrollview

Comment: Don't even need any WebView. Nor all that level nesting, which is really a performance-killer!

Comment: Frank, I think you didnt understand the question, I am showing html content in webview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot and finally resolved the issue,I removed the scrollview and added the content of scrollview into header and footer of listview.

thanks to all for support, I think its not a good way to use scrollview with listview.